# Onmouseover call ruby function in Volt framework not working

Tags: ruby, voltrb

I want to call a function when the mouse is on an aside, but it only calls it on the initial page load (which it shouldn't) and not when the mouse is on the aside. Here is my code:

```
<aside onmouseover="{{ func_name }}">
  ...
<aside>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Events in volt are bound with e-, so you want to do an e-mounseover attribute: